# Variant of the Schur Complement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, linear-matrix-inequality, schur-complement

Let $$M = \left(\begin{array}{cc}{A} & {B} \\ {B^{T}} & {C}\end{array}\right)$$ be symmetric, and let $A$ be invertible. Then the Schur Complement Lemma suggests that $$C-B^{T} A^{-1} B \succeq 0 \implies M \succeq 0$$

Is there an analogous result for the following expression? $$C-B^{T} A^{-2} B \succeq 0$$ such that it can be setup as valid linear LMI constraint in some existing SDP solver.

Comment: How about the following? $$\begin{bmatrix} I & A^{-1} B \\ B^T A^{-1} & C\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$$

Comment: But that is a non-linear SDP constraint. Existing solvers will not allow that.

Comment: Usually, the first letters of the Latin alphabet are used to denote knowns, rather than unknowns.